# How to ask protoc to use a value instead of a pointer as the value side of a map with Go?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am using protocol buffers defined like this:

```
message Index {
     message albums {
         repeated string name = 1;
     }
     map<string, albums> artists_albums= 1;
     map<int32, albums> year_albums = 2;
}
```

It generates go code like this:

```
type Index struct {
    ArtistsAlbums map[string]*IndexAlbums
    YearAlbums     map[int32]*IndexAlbums
 }
```

How can I make it generate map values of type `IndexAlbums` instead of `*IndexAlbums`?

Answer (score 2):

If you use [gogoprotobuf](https://godoc.org/github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto) then there is an extension that will allow that

```
map<string, albums> artists_albums = 1 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
```

With regular goprotobuf I don't believe there is a way.

> nullable, if false, a field is generated without a pointer (see warning below).
>
> Warning about nullable: According to the Protocol
> Buffer specification, you should be able to tell whether a field is
> set or unset. With the option nullable=false this feature is lost,
> since your non-nullable fields will always be set. It can be seen as a
> layer on top of Protocol Buffers, where before and after marshalling
> all non-nullable fields are set and they cannot be unset.